# Will pushing an old commit overwrite more recent already pushed commits?

Tags: git

Hi there,

I don't know if the title is clear enough...
I have made a commit a few days ago and I forgot to push it.
Since then, I have made other commits and I pushed them.
Now, I want to push the old commit but I am afraid it would overwrite my most recent commits.

I mean, let's say, in the old commit, I have modified the method 'myMethod:'. In an other commit I modified this method again, and that's the version I want to keep.
What will happen if I now push the first commit ? Will this method be "reset" ?

Comment: Did you switch branches (with checkout) between making the earlier commits and the new one?

Comment: Yes I did, could it be a problem ?

Comment: What you should do depends on which commit is on which branch and which commit should be pushed to which branch. Without describing that you can't get reasonable advice (except the fact, that without `-f`, `git push` will never discard anything).

Comment: All the commits I am talking about are on or should be pushed to the same branch. The accepted answer was correct in my case, I am now reading some more docs about git :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push will just transfer all your commits (that happened since the last push/pull operation), in the proper sequence, to the other Repository, nothing will get overwritten.

Comment: The OP does not understand how git commits are sequenced. 'Proper' doesn't mean anything to him.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's actually what I thought but I preferred to ask. And @JimMaguire, I'll look into what you told me to google.

Comment: False. Push will not automatically transfer all your commits!

Comment: What you mean? Every time i do `push` all my commits get pushed. Or none, if there is something wrong. Of course, only the commits from the current branch gets pushed, other branches won't be touched.